# Fixing fonts antialiasing after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04? (What rendering engines are at hand?)

Tags: xorg, fonts, 18.04, wayland, antialiasing

I have upgraded from Ubuntu +17.10 to 18.04.
After that, Gnome wouldn't start - I got a login loop, until I deleted `~/.config/dconf/user`. That way I lost all configuration but I have set it back.

However, I can't get the antialiasing to work. I have tried all 3 options in Gnome Tweaks, but I can still see that some fonts are rendered weirdly - with some kind of colorful halo around them. It only seems to happen in some programs, e.g. Intellij IDEA which I think uses GTK through Java, but not sure at all.

Is there some secondary options I have to set? I remember some settings are duplicated between Gnome and KDE. There are Wayland and X. As per [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/xorg-will-default-display-server-ubuntu-18-04-lts), I had X but now I should have Wayland. How do I know which one I have? Could switching to the other help (or break more things? :) )